# How to implement a signature checker for the signature scheme BLS?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, liquidity, cryptography, implementation

We are willing to implement a signature checker for the signature scheme BLS (or BLS12-381). To the best of our knowledge, it may not be too painful since the smart contract language already supports arbitrary large integers.

However, we have no idea about how to implement it? Can anyone guide us and/or show us some example implementation for the other schemes?

Comment: Just for info could you precise what example use case you would have for using bls ? Also could you precise why it would be sufficient for you to have it implemented as smart contract vs a primitive of michelson say ? Tx!

Comment: We are willing to use it for implementing Lightning Factories for Tezos. We are not really sure how and in which level to do it, I wrote implemented as smart contract because Arthur Breitman told me that we can do it like that. If there is another and more convinient way, we will be happy to hear about it.

Comment: smartpy should probably let you do that fairly easily as there is an existing python implementation of bls12-381

Comment: Can you provide the link about the python implementation of bls12-381? I was unable to find it on internet.

Comment: https://github.com/Chia-Network/bls-signatures

Comment: Are there similar example implemetation for Tezos that can help us understand how we can implement it?

Answer (score 0):

BLS has now been implemented in tezos. See the [merge request](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/5444).